# C++ c_str() strange behavior

Tags: c++

I got the following program:

```
std::string f() {
    return "f";
}

std::string g() {
    return "g";
}

int main() {
    const char *s = f().c_str();
    std::cout << "s = " << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "g() = " << g() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "s = " << s << std::endl;
}
```

I would expect to see s always print out "f", but the following is what I get:

```
s = f
g() = g
s = g
```

I have been scratching my hair for hours but still haven't figured out what is going wrong.

Comment: Your pointer `s` doesn't point to a valid object by the time you attempt to use it, because it is pointing to the data of a temporary string object that doesn't live long enough. You are invoking *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: +1 for OP updating post 3 days later to clarify that he/she is not bald

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pointer `s` is invalid when you print it because the temporary `std:string` being a result of a call to `f()` is destroyed at that point (the destruction happens at the and of your full-expression at the first line of `main` function).

Try this one:

```
int main() {
  std::string f_string = f();
  const char *s = f_string.c_str();
  std::cout << "s = " << s << std::endl;
  std::cout << "g() = " << g() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "s = " << s << std::endl;
}
```

Now it should work as the string the `c_str` is called is still in the scope when accessing the pointer.

Comment: Thanks Krizz for the answer, it makes thing much clearer now.